# How to implement the smart-crop feature

Tags: android, image-processing

I am trying to implement a mobile application that has a feature of smart-crop (that is similar to CamScanner). What exactly is this feature called and how to implement this feature ?

[image: Auto-Crop feature from CamScanner]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this git hub link, it exactly matches your requirement. [ScanLibrary](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo)